# Reporting With Angular 6 and .net core mvc

Tags: angular, .net-core, reporting, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am developing a project using Angular 6 and .net core MVC. But Reporting option is not available at .net core. Can any one suggest how i activate RDLC reporting in .net core or any free reporting tool for Angular 6 or .net core